# Check if a content of a binary file is in a part/whole binary file (C lang)

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I have two files:

```
    FILE* fileToScan = fopen("c:/fileToScan.png", "rb");
    FILE* contentFile = fopen("c:/virusFile.jpg", "rb");
```

I want to check if the content of contentFile is in (/part of) fileToScan.
Any help?

Comment: `strstr` works once you read both files. The "hardest" part is to read both files with proper memory allocation

Comment: I'd memory map the files and use `memmem()` (or whatever the Windows equivalent is, if any)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `strstr` will work with text files only. One wants `memmem` for binary data

Comment: `strstr()` is very much the wrong function for binary data, though.

Comment: I can't use memmem

Comment: that's true. If there's a 0 then it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Simple" solution:

1. read the whole file to scan in memory. You can use variable `char *haystack;` with size `size_t haystack_len;`
2. read the whole content file in memory. You can use variable `char *needle;` with size `size_t needle_len;`
3. run a `memchr()` on haystack using the first character of needle
4. if you find the first character try a `memcmp()` from that point
5. if the `memcmp()` fails you can update the haystack pointer to one past the `memchr()` result and go back to step 3

This is using no optimization at all! You can find definitely find better implementations like [the glibc one](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/memmem.c.html).

If the file doesn't fit in memory, things are going to be harder. You basically need to work in chunks.